# Background to be visible on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently the background of my `.menu` is red. What I am trying to achieve is:
have this background not visible until it is clicked. (and obviously return the state when clicked to close the menu.

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Dicta, aliquam doloremque harum labore.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Rerum enim ab, distinctio voluptatum?</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Harum doloremque eveniet porro ratione.</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Cupiditate et similique eius deserunt.</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```css
menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 30px;
    left: 11px;
    background: #ed1c24;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms linear 250ms;
    -o-transition: all 250ms linear 250ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 250ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms linear 250ms;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you any demo will help more.

Comment: I do, do you have an email?

Comment: Just create fiddle and give link here do not need email.

Comment: @Clarke: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @Sadikhasan - Can the content behind be blurred too?
http://jsfiddle.net/clarkecribb/7a5y0dbr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this the solution you need?

```
.menu:active, .menu:focus, .menu:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}

.menu
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you need ?
first remove `.menu` background color and on click add background color `red`.

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
   $('.menu').css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.menu').click(function(){
   $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.menu.active {
  background:red; 
}
```

and remove hard code color and opacity when you add jquery code in script tag in body ofter your html code  and also add jquery library on html header section then jquery code work

when class is add on menu then .menu.active css run and when again click remove class and also remove BG color [also check this ][1]

[enter link description here][1]

[1]:

```js
var main=function(){
 $('.menu ul li').click(function()
 { 
  $('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  
 });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  
  float:left;
}

.menu a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 20px;
}/* CSS Document */
.menu li:hover a,
.menu li.active a{
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;
}
.dropdownM,
.dropdown{
 border:1px solid #666;
 display:none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="dropdown">
           <p>press any key</p>
          </div>
          
          <div class="dropdownM">
           <p>You press M key</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```